# How to inform R that an escaped character (em-dash) is finished when the string is composed by numbers?

Tags: r

The answer is probably simple but I am unable to find it. 
When plotting in R I want to add a text in the plot containing a number range (e.g. 60-80) with a code like this:

```
a<-rnorm(10,10)
b<-rnorm(10,10)
plot(a,b)
text(10,10,labels=("60\u2013 80"))
```

I got the following text  in the plot: "60- 80", with an annoying space after the dash. 
Obviously when trying `("60\201380")` it simply fails. I cannot use the direct way `("60-80")` because it doesn't work with Arial in my computer.

Any idea to tell R that `\u2013` has finished?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You missed the `u` when you didn't have the space. It works with the `u` for me.

Comment: you're right... it works. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 10):

Just paste it. :)

```
text(10,10,labels=paste("60\u2013","80", sep=""))
```

and it works.

[image: Example]

Comment: +1 or even just `paste0( ... )` which is short-hand for `paste( .... , sep = "" )`

Comment: At least I have learned how to use the paste function... Thank you

Comment: @gonzalosánchez if you're satisfied then maybe you could accept the answer so we can close the question? :)